# sorting in sql based on a part of a column(number)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column with values as below

```
18 ABC
45 XYZ
1 ABC
83 DEF
22 XYZ
4 ABC
```

I want them to be sorted as below while pulling the values from oracle DB

```
1 ABC
4 ABC
18 ABC
22 XYZ
45 XYZ
83 DEF
```

when I use order by `substr(column,1)` it is not giving the result as expected **4 ABC** will go down after **22 XYZ**

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Wouldn't that result be expected as substr('22 XYZ',1) should give `2` and thus be sorted before `4`?

Comment: Fix the table might be the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do the ff:

```
order by to_number(substr(column, 1, instr(column, ' ')))
```

Comment: it worked, thanks but what if there is no space between the number and the word like 4ABC ?

Comment: I can give a number instead of instr if I know how many digits it would be, but this may change over the time..hmmm

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like `ORDER BY CAST(substr(column, 2) AS INT)`?